Using column header to write variables to replace columns from different csv files (using awk)
I have been working on making a bash script generic so that it would allow for input csv files with a different number of columns.
I want to replace one column in a csv file with another column from a different csv file. I know how to do this with the column number but column numbers may vary so I want to use the headers of these two columns instead.
These are my files
cat test4.csv
2xedni
GCGATTAC
CATCACTT

cat test1.csv
Sample_ID,Sample_Name,Sample_Plate,Sample_Well,I7_Index_ID,index,I5_Index_ID,index2,Sample_Project,Description
1,O_bru,1,A01,UDI_55,GACAGTAA,UDI_55,GTAATCGC,,
2,A_lych,1,B01,UDI_56,CCTTCGCA,UDI_56,AAGTGATG,,

My desired output is test5.csv
Sample_ID,Sample_Name,Sample_Plate,Sample_Well,I7_Index_ID,index,I5_Index_ID,index2,Sample_Project,Description
1,O_bru,1,A01,UDI_55,GACAGTAA,UDI_55,GCGATTAC
2,A_lych,1,B01,UDI_56,CCTTCGCA,UDI_56,CATCACTT

I thought about using variables in a awk command this way
var1=$(awk '$1=="2xedni" {p=1} p' test4.csv)
var2=$(awk '$1=="index2" {p=1} p' test1.csv)

awk -v var="$var1" -v varr="$var2" 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=var;next}{varr=a[FNR]}1' test4.csv test1.csv > test5.csv 

All I am getting is test4.csv and the replacement of the columns has not occurred.
I noticed that when I echo $var2 is empty so I am guessing that is the problem as well?
Am I doing something wrong? Any suggestion?
Thanks, Giulia

Your desired output isn't a valid CSV as the rows don't contain the same number of fields than the header (the rows should end with ,,)

The answers posted in the questions that your previous question was closed as a dup of show you how to do this. Please read them and try to use what you learn THEN ask a question showing your code based on one of those answers if you get stuck.

cut and paste could be another option: To replace column 8, try paste -d, <(cut -d, -f-7 test1.csv) test4.csv <(cut -d, -f9- test1.csv) > test5.csv.

will the file with replacement data (test4.csv in this case) always have just one column; if the file could have multiple columns then please show such an example

will the column header(s) in the replacement file (test4.csv in this case) always be the reverse of the column header of the main file? in the samples provided we're talking about index2 vs 2xedni

@markp-fuso yes, the file test4.csv will always have one column.

@markp-fuso yes, the header of the column in test4.csv will always be the reverse! 2xedni. Thanks


Am I doing something wrong?

This code
awk -v var="$var1" -v varr="$var2" 'FNR==NR{a[NR]=var;next}{varr=a[FNR]}1' test4.csv test1.csv > test5.csv

does only alter a array and varr variable value, it does nothing to fields of row, so 1 does just print row as is.

Any suggestion?

Firstly you should inform GNU AWK to use , both as field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS). You should assign values to fields of rows, consider following example, let say you have file.csv
Able,Baker,Charlie
1,2,3
4,5,6

and that you need to set all zeros in column by providing its' name, then you might do
awk -v col="Baker" 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=1){columns[$i]=i};print}NR>1{$(columns[col])=0;print}' file.csv

gives output
Able,Baker,Charlie
1,0,3
4,0,6

Explanation: I inform GNU AWK , is both field separator (FS) and output field separator (OFS), when processing 1st line I populate array columns so keys are names and position are values and print 1st line as is. For later lines I find position of columns using created arrays and set value for that field to zero.
(tested in GNU Awk 5.1.0)

this doesn't address OP's requirement to obtain replacement values from a separate file
